# How do I record slow motion video on the LG G5?

Tags: camera

With the camera in auto mode I can select slo-mo from the mode menu and it displays 'Tap (camera) to record slow motion video'.

However, when I record it's at normal speed and I see no options for changing the record speed.

Any help appreciated...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does actually record in Slow motion but you need to go to the inbuilt LG video player to play back in slow speed. It is here that you can modify the speed when you edit the video. You can also set sections of the video to work in certain speeds which is pretty cool.

Comment: Thanks - accessing the video via gallery works fine (I was using google photo)